# Url gets stripped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue where I can console log the url when it in a var but the moment that I add it back to the page within html it strips the forward slashes.

does anyone know why this would happen. I have tried to change this in any way possible but I am coming up short on why this is happening.

```
function hiddenlinks() {
    var urllink = $(".hidden-small").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("href");
    }).get().reverse();
    console.log(urllink);
    var spantext = $(".hidden-small span").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get(); 
    for ( var i = 0; i < urllink.length; i++ ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < spantext.length; i++ ) {
            console.log(urllink[i])
            var urlencode = urllink[i];
            console.log(urlencode);
            var finlink = '<li><a href"'+urlencode+'">'+spantext[i]+'</a></li>'
            $( finlink ).prependTo( ".paradeiser_children" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result in the console?

Comment: `<a href="'+urlencode+'"` perhaps adding the equal sign helps?

Comment: I hope this isn't your original indentation...

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle or jsbin demonstrating this problem? I can not observe this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9dpk2xt/

Comment: @cDima Now I feel completly stupid. All that trouble shooting and I forgot and html =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I am guessing that you have the same number of `SPAN`s as the number of `links` and trying to construct those many `LI`s. You could make it a bit more simpler/cleaner using `$.each()` as below.

```
function hiddenlinks() {
    var urllink = $(".hidden-small").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("href");
    }).get().reverse();
    console.log(urllink);

    var spantext = $(".hidden-small span").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    var $items = $();
    $.each(urllink, function(i, url) {

        $items = $items.add(
            $("<li/>", {
                html: '<a href="' + url + '">' + spantext[i] + '</a>'
            })
        );
    });
    $(".paradeiser_children").prepend($items);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a better way to write the loop. I learned something new today. You also fixed the error within your code by adding an = after href

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
for ( var i = 0; i < urllink.length; i++ ) {
     for ( var i = 0; i < spantext.length; i++ ) {
```

to

```
for ( var i = 0; i < urllink.length; i++ ) {
     for ( var j = 0; j < spantext.length; j++ ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an missing equal sign after the `href`:

```
 <a href="'+urlencode+'"
```